# How to center this code?

Tags: html, css, center, centering

Please help me to center the code below and tell me how you did that:

```
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}

div.iframe:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zuntcod0/

Comment: And in what way (horizontally or vertically) ?

Comment: horizontally please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center the videos, you have to use `text-align: center;`, but that doesn't work with floating elements. Remove `float: left;` at the video divs and replace it with `display: inline-block`. It looks like this:

(New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zuntcod0/2/)

```css
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
}

div.iframe:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="fjords.jpg">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cw7cOOQt5KM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="fjords.jpg">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cw7cOOQt5KM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="fjords.jpg">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cw7cOOQt5KM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="fjords.jpg">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cw7cOOQt5KM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="fjords.jpg">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cw7cOOQt5KM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to easily center these elements horizontally, you could consider taking your outermost `<div>` element, defining an explicit width for it and using `margin: 0 auto` to center that within the page overall :

```
<div id='wrapper'>
     <!-- Your Content Here -->
</div>
```

along with :

```
#wrapper { 
     width: 800px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Example**

You can [see a working example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/horuzi/edit?css,output) and what the output looks like below :

[image]